# Rendering itemviews in marionetteJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, marionette

Recently I have been fiddling around with JS frameworks. Being new to BackboneJS I'm running stuck on the most simplest of things. The rendering of an itemView.

I made a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRxuW0YKbHM1pagDB8aK). I'm sure it's something stupidly simple, but I can't seem to find the problem. The console shows no errors for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have just one small error,
in your in index.html you have this

```
<div id="#content">  // you dont need the # there
```

remove it and it will work

```
<div id="content">
```

Comment: Thanks. I swear I looked over this like ten time and just did not see it. Mistakes are made when tired...